# Pass field variables to hyperlink in master page in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, href

I am trying pass customer number field value to `href` `url` 
"http://abc.yyy/id=12&custnum="
And in my code behind page i am having my field value

```
string custnum=txtcustnum.Text;
```

Now how to pass this `custnum` to `href` link in `masterpage.aspx`

Comment: How you are forming/Creating  this URL?

Answer (score 1):

In your master page create hyperlink as below

```
<asp:HyperLink id="myLink" Text="Click Here" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your content page code behind access this Master Page hyperlink and set its url

```
HyperLink hyperLinkMasterPage = this.Master.FindControl("myLink") as HyperLink;
string custnum=txtcustnum.Text;
hyperLinkMasterPage.NavigateUrl  = @"http://abc.yyy/id=12&custnum=" + custnum;
```